# How to create a dataframe caclulator with flask and google spreadsheets and display the results

Tags: python, dataframe, flask

I wanted to create a simple Datatable calculator which simply takes data from an html form, does an addition-by-row with a column from google's spreadsheets and outputs a new table on the same page as my html form.

Now I have tried to write a flask app, using [Flask-ex's template](https://github.com/anfederico/Flaskex), so I can display my data but I can't. Even with flask's debugger doesn't output any errors.

**What do you think I should?**

Below you will find two pastebins with that code as well as how I tried to display my code:

[HTML](https://pastebin.com/2kTRdtF5):

```
{{ans | safe}}
{{ans_factor | safe}}
```

[Python](https://pastebin.com/m5td96W0):

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['POST'])
def submit():

    #Set up the creds to access spreadsheet
    SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', SCOPE)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    #Access the first page of our spreadsheet
    sheet = client.open('Survey_Responses').sheet1


    #Assign the data that we accessed from the previous line to a variable
    responses = sheet.get_all_records()
    resp_df=pd.DataFrame(responses) #Convert list to DataFrame
    resp_select_ans=resp_df.iloc[0,1:37] /10
    ans_factor=pd.DataFrame(resp_df.iloc[0:6,41])

    ans=resp_select_ans.values.reshape((6,6))
    return render_template('/home', ans=ans.to_html(),ans_factor=ans_factor.to_html())
```

Comment: Did you try to return soemthing trivial? E.g.last line: return "hello world"?

Comment: I tried numbers, like "32"

Comment: Ok, some more considerations: Are you using the builtin server? How do you perform the request? Do you get a HTTP response? If so, what status code is it and what is the content? It seems you are not passing any data to your submit method, can you make do with a GET instead of POST? Is there any route that you do get a response on?... there are a lot of variables here :)

Comment: @g_uint both HTML and Python codes are linked to pastebin as hypertexts on my post.But to answer your questions; 

The server is from google's spreadseet and it is where I will later store the results. 

I perform the request using GET-POST. I don't get an HTTP response. 

Yes, I get in every route except this one, which is why I'm looking into it.

Comment: Not getting an HTTP response would indicate your script has not reached its return statement yet.